# How to find level 60 items with a level 70 character?

Tags: diablo-iii

Before the last update it was possible to start a game on normal or nightmare or hell difficulty and in such a game a character with a high level was able to find items with lower level. But now I find only level 70 items with a level 70 character even if I play on normal difficulty. How to find level 60 items with a level 70 character?

Comment: The new Loot 2.0 system is designed so that the drops you get are (relatively) useful for your character. Therefore, you cannot get level 60 items on a level 70 character (unless you join a level 60 game?).

Comment: @Bunyip What is a level 60 game?

Comment: If a level 60 character creates a game and then you join that game with your level 70 you might get level 60 items. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Why do you want level 60 items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is nowadays superficial, because of the [gem of ease](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem-of-ease). The gem can be used to remove every level requirement. I use it always in seasons to level secondary characters. A level 70 weapon with this gem makes it easy to play a level 1 character even on torture 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want nice items for a Lv60 character from Lv70, the best way is to look for items with reduced level requirements. That way you get high level items without the high level requirements. The drawback for this method is it's a bit slower.

Novarg's answer will also do it, but of course level 70 items are better than level 60. But level 60 items drop everywhere at level 60, so it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why would you want level 60 items, but there is only 1 way to get level 60 items while you play a level 70 character: join a level 60 game.

How to do it:

- Ask a friend who has a level 60 character to create a game
- Join this game
- Now you can go and find level 60 items

Just don't forget, that if your friend levels up in this game, the game level will rise to 61 and you will start getting level 61 items.

Comment: If the friend leaves the game, does it remain at 60?

Comment: @PeterL I'm pretty sure it does. This is also a great way to get through rifts really fast. Start it with a level 1 character.

Comment: @PeterL yes if everyone leave the game still remain at level 60, only recreating the game can change its level (or if the host level up but here we're assuming he's gone from the game)

Comment: Level 60 game is mandatory if you want to earn gem crafting achievements, and do not want to beg around whole Battle.net for low-level gems.